# How to solve "semi-colon expected" warnings (css-semicolonexpected)

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, nuxt.js, tailwind-css

I'm trying to use Tailwindcss `@apply` directive in a `<style>` tag of a Nuxt.js Vue file. Everything works fine, but I keep getting some annoying red squiggly lines. Please, guys, I need help... Thank you!

Below is a [screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hslPg.png) and a snippet:

[image]

```html
<style scoped>

.title {
  @apply text-orient font-light block text-5xl pt-2;
}

.message {
  @apply font-light pb-4 text-orient text-2xl text-blue-bayoux
}
</style>
```

Answer (score 60):

There is no built-in way to solve this within VS Code. The recommended way to solve this is by making use of the Stylelint extension to handle your CSS linting (& SCSS and/or Less, etc.). It's very powerful and likely will improve your stylesheets beyond removing these errors for you.

1. You need to add the styleint dependencies to your project. Run:

```sh
npm install --save-dev stylelint stylelint-config-standard

yarn add -D stylelint stylelint-config-standard
```

2. Create a `stylelint.config.js` in the root of your project. *(same location where your package.json is stored)*

Place this snippet into it:

```js
module.exports = {
  extends: ["stylelint-config-standard"],
  rules: {
    "at-rule-no-unknown": [
      true,
      {
        ignoreAtRules: [
          "tailwind",
          "apply",
          "variants",
          "responsive",
          "screen",
        ],
      },
    ],
    "declaration-block-trailing-semicolon": null,
    "no-descending-specificity": null,
  },
};
```

3. Install these extensions to your VS Code setup:

- [Stylelint](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=stylelint.vscode-stylelint)
- [Tailwind CSS IntelliSense](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=bradlc.vscode-tailwindcss)

4. Last but not least, adjust your local or global VS Code `settings.json` file to include:

```js
"css.validate": false,
"less.validate": false,
"scss.validate": false,
```

This way you will have the native linting "disabled", but are still ensuring it is linted using the Tailwind IntelliSense plugin.

Comment: I needed to run `npx stylelint "**/*.css" --fix` afterwards to help fix the highlighted issues.

Comment: My `settings.json` is this:
```
{
    "emmet.excludeLanguages": [
        "markdown"
    ],
    "emmet.includeLanguages": {
        "erb": "html",
        "html-eex": "html"
    },
    "editor.fontSize": 13,
    "workbench.iconTheme": "material-icon-theme",
    "workbench.colorTheme": "Material Theme Darker High Contrast",
    "json.schemas": [
    
    ]
}
```
Where I put these values? 
```
"css.validate": false,
"less.validate": false,
"scss.validate": false,
```inside `json.schemas`?

Comment: Thanks, this seems to work the best for my React/Prettier/SASS project!

Comment: If you want to make it work as November 2021, add in your VS Code settings: `"stylelint.validate": ["css", "less", "postcss", "vue"]`. And in stylelint config: `'"overrides": [
    {
      "files": ["**/*.vue"],
      "customSyntax": "postcss-html"
    }
  ],` You also must install `npm install --save-dev postcss-html`

Answer (score 28):

**Disable Vetur's style validation**

Such CSS warnings may originate from the Vetur extension, which may very well be the case if the warning's icon (as seen in VSCode's "Problems" pane) is a Vue logo.

By disabling Vetur's style validation, you may lose other benefits. Although, in the long-run, it's probably better to rely on a more full-featured validator/linter than this extension.

1. Go to the Vetur extension settings and uncheck the option for style validation.

--- or ---

2. Set the option per-project, in a `.vscode/settings.json` file in the project root, with the following:

   `"vetur.validation.style": false`

---

**Vetur warnings look something like:**

[image: vetur is the guilty one here]

Answer (score 27):

I found another solution [Usage of Tailwind with nuxt lead to weird @apply issue *#300*](https://github.com/tailwindlabs/discuss/issues/300)

Just add `lang="postcss"` to `style` tag and with this fix, I haven't any error.

```html
<style lang="postcss" scoped>
  .title {
      @apply text-purple-600 font-bold;
  }
</style>
```

Comment: I tried your suggestion and it does get rid of the error message but I would still recommend to go with the most upvoted solution and integrate stylelint because it will add the ability to reveal potential errors in your css. I think thats very valuable.

Answer (score 20):

i think you are using prettier and that plugin get error when you make `@apply` in one line so try this:

```
<style scoped>
.title {
  @apply text-orient;
  @apply font-light;
  @apply block;
  @apply text-5xl;
  @apply pt-2;
}

.message {
  @apply font-light;
  @apply pb-4;
  @apply text-orient;
  @apply text-2xl;
  @apply text-blue-bayoux;
}
</style>
```

Comment: Ali Hosseini, I am not using prettier. However, your suggestion worked; but I would also want to know how to avoid having @apply across multiple lines. Thank you!

Comment: What is your ide?!

Comment: i'm not familiar with svcode and i don't know it at all, but if you mean vscode so right click on the page and select `Format Document With...` and check what is your code formater ( I believe the problem is with your formater)

Comment: Sorry, I intend to say vscode. However, it is resolved. I had to disable a certain extension (vetur) that was using prettier to format the codebase. All is fine now. Thanks!

Comment: thanks, this works specifically in angular project using prettier for linting with tailwind

Answer (score 11):

### 2 Steps

1. Add the lines below into: .vscode > settings.json

```
"css.validate": false,
"less.validate": false,
"scss.validate": false,
```

2. Install StyleLint Extension

```
https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items/shinnn.stylelint
```

Restart, it's done!

Comment: I'm using less, I just added "less.validate": false, to .vscode settings.json file and it worked, thanks!

Answer (score 7):

I had the same problem with Nuxt and the solution was to follow the steps [in this blog](https://www.meidev.co/blog/visual-studio-code-css-linting-with-tailwind/), the TL:DR is:

1. Install the stylelint vscode extension
2. Add this configuration in your stylelint.config.js

```
rules: {
   'at-rule-no-unknown': [
     true,
     {
       ignoreAtRules: [
         'tailwind',
         'apply',
         'variants',
         'responsive',
         'screen',
       ],
     },
   ],
   'declaration-block-trailing-semicolon': null,
   'no-descending-specificity': null,
 },
```

3. In the vscode configuration uncheck the option css validate or add this to your vscode settings.json file `"css.validate": false`

with this steps all will work perfect.

**Just in case**, I had a problem with the prettier formatting too, and it was fixed with this option in my vscode settings.json file `"vetur.format.defaultFormatter.html": "prettier",`

Comment: `"vetur.validation.style": false,` fixed things for me with the stylelint setup.

Comment: I don't know the essence of having the stylelint though because applying just the 3rd step fixed it for me.

Comment: The first two steps are just in case your project use Stylelint.

Answer (score 7):

Try adding the extension **[PostCSS Language Support](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=csstools.postcss)**; it adds support for modern and experimental CSS within Visual Studio Code.

Comment: This answer is too short and not specific enough. You could've added at least an explanation and a link to the documentation for the suggested package.

Comment: This is more of a comment, than an answer. At 50+ reputation, you may post comments. See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment) for details.

Comment: I edited Imane's good answer to clarify what I believe their intent was.

Comment: This extension did nothing for me... because the warnings I had originated from yet another extension. The general answer is: Find out what extension is reporting the warning, and deal with it.

Comment: Note that you will likely need to select PostCSS as the current language for the document you're working in. This was necessary for me before it worked properly.

Answer (score 0):

I use VS Code and added the following to my settings:

```json
"files.associations": {
  "*.vue": "html"
}
```

Afterwards, the error was gone.